# Identify first non-zero element within a group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks like the following. The rightmost column is my desired column:

```
Group   Value   Target_Column   
1        0         0     
1        0         0  
1        1         1
1        2         0
2        0         0
2        1         1
2        0         0
2        1         0
```

How do I identify the first non-zero value in a group(`Group`) and then create a column that retains the first non-zero value and show all else as zeroes?

I have been trying to leverage `idxmax` for this as stated in this solution:
[Find first non-zero value in each column of pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586146/find-first-non-zero-value-in-each-column-of-pandas-dataframe)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 'Value': [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1]})
df.ne(0).idxmax()
g = df.groupby('Group').Value
g.ne(0).idxmax()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `idxmax`

```
df['Newcol']=0
df.loc[df.Value.ne(0).groupby(df['Group']).idxmax(),'Newcol']=1
df
Out[41]: 
   Group  Value  Target_Column  Newcol
0      1      0              0       0
1      1      0              0       0
2      1      1              1       1
3      1      2              0       0
4      2      0              0       0
5      2      1              1       1
6      2      0              0       0
7      2      1              0       0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am noticing that for groups that have no non-zero values(all of them are 0s in `Value` column), `NewCol` shows a 1 for the first element. How do I show zeroes for all elements if there are no non-zero element?

Comment: @gibbz00 doing this for protection `df.loc[df.Newcol.eq(0),'Newcol']=0
` at the end

Comment: Thanks. I think you meant `df.loc[df.Value.eq(0),'Newcol']=0 `