# Find first non-zero element within a group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that you can see how it is in the following. The column named `target` is my desired column:

```
group    value    target

  1        1        0
  1        2        0
  1        3        2
  1        4        0
  1        5        1
  2        1        0
  2        2        0
  2        3        0
  2        4        1
  2        5        3
```

Now I want to find the first non-zero value in the `target` column for each group and remove rows before that row in each group. So the output should be like this:

```
group    value    target

  1        3        2
  1        4        0
  1        5        1
  2        4        1
  2        5        3
```

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51583908/identify-first-non-zero-element-within-a-group-in-pandas), but I don't how to change the code to get my desired result.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the groupby, set `sort` to `False`, get the `cumsum`, then filter for rows not equal to `0` :

```
df.loc[df.groupby(["group"], sort=False).target.cumsum() != 0]

    group   value   target
2      1       3    2
3      1       4    0
4      1       5    1
8      2       4    1
9      2       5    3
```

Answer (score 1):

This shoul do. I'm sure you can do it with less `reset_index()`, but this shouldn't affect too much the speed if your dataframe isn't too big:

```
idx = dff[dff.target.ne(0)].reset_index().groupby('group').index.first()
mask = (dff.reset_index().set_index('group')['index'].ge(idx.to_frame()['index'])).values
df_final = dff[mask]
```

#### Output:

```
0  group value  target
3      1     3       2
4      1     4       0
5      1     5       1
9      2     4       1
10     2     5       3
```