# Identify first & last non-zero elements within a group in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

**[Solutions]**
[Identify the first & last non-zero elements/indices within a group in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70085119/identify-the-first-last-non-zero-elements-indices-within-a-group-in-numpy/70090734#70090734)

========= [Previous question]. **Please ignore the followings** =========

I have numpy arrays like the following:

```
group = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2])  
arr1 = np.array([0,0,0,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,0,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,0,0])  
arr2 = np.array([0,0,0,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,0,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,0,0])  

target_arr = np.array([0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,2,2,2,0,0])
```

For group 1, the first non-zero/nan element is 2 in arr1 at index 4. For group 2, it is 2 in arr1 and arr2 at index 2. How do I identify the first-appearing & the first-non-zero/nan value for each group in multiple arrays (i.e. only one value for each group), and ffill the values to create one array (like target_arr aobve) without iteration?

I found a similar answer by using pandas. How do I do it in pure numpy?
[Identify first non-zero element within a group in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51583908/identify-first-non-zero-element-within-a-group-in-pandas)

Comment: Do you include NaN in "non-zero"? Or would you treat it as a zero?

Comment: @user17242583 Thanks for your quick reply. Treat it as a zero please. Or you may ffill arr1 to get an array like np.array([0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,2,2,2,0,0])

Answer (score 1):

There are few essential things you can do:

- precalculate `target_arr` (use [advanced indexing](https://towardsdatascience.com/numpy-indexing-explained-c376abb2440d)):

  ```
  arr = np.array([arr1, arr2])
  arr = arr[group-1, np.arange(len(group))]
  >>> arr
  array([ 0.,  0.,  0., nan,  2., nan, nan,  0., nan,  2., nan, nan,  0., 0.])
  ```
- find indices of nan values (use [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html)):

  ```
  idx = np.flatnonzero(np.isnan(arr)) #idx of nan values: [3,  5,  6,  8, 10, 11]
  ```
- find indices of the most previous non `nan` items (use [`np.maximum.accumulate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html)):

  ```
  prev = np.arange(len(arr))
  prev[idx] = 0
  prev = np.maximum.accumulate(prev)
  >>> prev
  array([ 0,  1,  2,  2,  4,  4,  4,  7,  7,  9,  9,  9, 12, 13], dtype=int32)
  ```
- fill them:

  ```
  >>> arr[prev]
  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0.])
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I rephrased my question a little bit. Sorry for the confusion.