# Identify the first & last non-zero elements/indices within a group in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

```
import numpy as np

group = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2])  
array = np.array([1,2,3,0,0,2,0,3,4,0,0,0,0,1])  
targt = np.array([1,1,1,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,1])  

def func(group: np.array, array: np.array):
    pass
    return array
```

- Step 1: Find the indexes of the first & last non-zero elements for
  each group, i.e. (0, 2) for group 0, (5, 8) for group 1, (13, 13) for
  group 2.
- Step 2: Replace the slices between each indexes with the
  first nan-zero value within each group, i,e, group 0 [1,2,3,0] ->
  [1,1,1,0], group 1 [0,2,0,3,4,0] -> [0,2,2,2,2,0], group 2 no change.

How could I do it without spliting arrays or iteration?

[Solutions]

```
def first_nonzero_index(arr: np.array, axis: int, mode: str = None, invalid_value: float = -1):
    mask = arr != 0
    if mode is None or mode == "head":
        return np.where(mask.any(axis=axis), mask.argmax(axis=axis), invalid_value)
    else:
        return np.where(mask.any(axis=axis),
                        arr.shape[axis] - np.flip(mask, axis=axis).argmax(axis=axis) - 1, invalid_value)

def func1(group: np.array, array: np.array):  # my solution
    group_size = np.bincount(group)[:-1]
    group_idx_end = np.cumsum(group_size)
    array_split = np.split(array, group_idx_end)

    concat_list = []
    for arr in array_split:
        idx_start = first_nonzero_index(arr, axis=0, mode="head")
        if idx_start != -1:
            idx_end = first_nonzero_index(arr, axis=0, mode="tail") + 1
            arr_ffill_first_nonzero = np.zeros_like(arr, dtype=float)
            arr_ffill_first_nonzero[idx_start:idx_end] = arr[idx_start]
            concat_list.append(arr_ffill_first_nonzero)
        else:
            concat_list.append(arr)
    return np.hstack(concat_list)

def fill(val):  # contributor @d.b
    inds = np.where(val != 0)[0]
    start, end = min(inds), max(inds)
    fill_val = val[start]
    val[start:end + 1] = fill_val
    return val

def split(val, grp):  # contributor @d.b
    arr = []
    curr = [val[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(val)):
        if grp[i] == grp[i - 1]:
            curr.append(val[i])
        else:
            arr.append(np.array(curr))
            curr = [val[i]]
    if curr:
        arr.append(np.array(curr))
    return arr

def func2(group, array):  # contributor @d.b
    return np.concatenate([fill(x) for x in split(array, group)])

def func3(group: np.array, array: np.array):  # my solution
    group_size = np.bincount(group)[:-1]
    group_idx_end = np.cumsum(group_size)
    array_split = np.split(array, group_idx_end)

    concat_list = []
    for arr in array_split:
        idx = np.where(arr != 0)[0]
        start, end = min(idx), max(idx)
        arr[start:end + 1] = arr[start]
        concat_list.append(arr)
    return np.hstack(concat_list)

def func4(group, array):  # contributor @d.b
    nonzero = (array != 0)
    _, marker_idx = np.unique(group[nonzero], return_index=True)
    nonzero_idx = np.arange(len(array))[nonzero]
    #STEP 2
    starts = np.minimum.reduceat(nonzero_idx, marker_idx)
    ends = np.maximum.reduceat(nonzero_idx, marker_idx)
    #STEP 3
    values = array[starts]
    out = np.zeros_like(array)
    out[starts] = values
    #check the case we can't insert the last negative value
    if ends[-1]+1==len(array):
        out[ends[:-1]+1] = -values[:-1]
    else:
        out[ends+1] = -values
    return np.cumsum(out)
```

Output: [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]

[Test]

```
n = 2000
group = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]*n)  # 30000
array = np.array([1,2,3,0,0,2,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]*n)
group = np.cumsum(group)
```

Run 100 times:

| func1 | func2 | func3 | func4 (Best solution) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9.70s | 2.54s | 1.99s | 0.03s |

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. SO is not a free code-writing service. Please make an honest attempt at solving the problem yourself and come back with **specific** questions about *your* code. Your question must include the code you have tried, any errors and your expected output.

Comment: Whats the output? Also please define np_shift function

Comment: @not_speshal I posted my solution. I think this is a specific question... I want to do it without spliting arrays or iteration.

Comment: @DaniMesejo Just added the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
group = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2])  
array = np.array([1,2,3,0,0,2,0,3,4,0,0,0,0,1])  
targt = np.array([1,1,1,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,1])
```

You can do the following steps:

- STEP 1. Find indices of nonzero items of `array` and mark the startings of new groups

  ```
  nonzero_idx -> [*0,1,2,/,*/,5,/,7,8,/,*/,/,/,13] (cross out slashes)
  marker_idx -> [0, 4, 10]
  ```
- STEP 2. Find starting and ending indices for each group, use [`np.ufunc.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html)

  ```
  starts -> [ 0,  5, 13]
  ends -> [ 2,  8, 13]
  ```
- STEP 3. Think of an `out` array such that `np.cumsum(out)` collapses into `target` array. Like so:

  ```
  [1,0,0,-1,0,2,0,0,0,-2,0,0,0,1] -> [1,1,1,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,1]
  ```

Now, code:

```
#STEP 1
nonzero = (array != 0)
_, marker_idx = np.unique(group[nonzero], return_index=True)
nonzero_idx = np.arange(len(array))[nonzero]
#STEP 2
starts = np.minimum.reduceat(nonzero_idx, marker_idx)
ends = np.maximum.reduceat(nonzero_idx, marker_idx)
#STEP 3
values = array[starts]
out = np.zeros_like(array)
out[starts] = values
#check the case we can't insert the last negative value
if ends[-1]+1==len(array): 
    out[ends[:-1]+1] = -values[:-1]
else:
    out[ends+1] = -values
>>> np.cumsum(out)
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int32)
```

No loops needed!

Comment: I learn new numpy function reduceat, haha. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def foo(s):
    chk = np.where(s > 0)[0]
    start = min(chk)
    end = max(chk)
    ans = [True if (start <= ind <= end) else False for ind in range(len(s))]
    return ans

pd.Series(array).groupby(group).transform(
    lambda x: x.mask(foo(x), x[x > 0].iloc[0])).to_numpy() 
# array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

#### 2

```
def split(val, grp):
    inds = np.where(np.append(False, grp[1:] != grp[:-1]))[0]
    return np.array_split(val, inds)

def fill(val):
    inds = np.where(val > 0)[0]
    start, end = min(inds), max(inds)
    val[start:end + 1] = val[start]
    return val

np.concatenate([fill(x) for x in split(array, group)])
# array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a solution in numpy without spliting arrays or iteration?

Comment: @wuya It is. You need intead to find indices of nonzero items + another indices that splits them. You're still able to find `starts` & `ends` in one go because splitting indices are sufficient with no actual split.

Comment: @d.b Thanks. I improved your method a little bit and posted above.