# PySpark drop leading zero values by group in dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, group-by, delete-row, leading-zero

I have this dataframe -

```
data = [(0,1,5,5,0,4),
        (1,1,5,6,0,7),
        (2,1,5,7,1,1), 
        (3,1,4,8,1,8), 
        (4,1,5,9,1,1), 
        (5,1,5,10,1,0),
        (6,2,3,4,0,2),
        (7,2,3,5,0,6),
        (8,2,3,6,3,8),
        (9,2,3,7,0,2),
        (10,2,3,8,0,6),
        (11,2,3,9,6,1)
      ]
data_cols = ["id","item","store","week","sales","inventory"]
data_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = data_)
display(deptDF)
```

What I want is to groupby on item, store and week and then delete all rows with leading 0 in sales per group, like so

```
data_new = [(2,1,5,7,1,1), 
        (3,1,4,8,1,8), 
        (4,1,5,9,1,1), 
        (5,1,5,10,1,0),
        (8,2,3,6,3,8),
        (9,2,3,7,0,2),
        (10,2,3,8,0,6),
        (11,2,3,9,6,1)
      ]
dep_cols = ["id","item","store","week","sales","inventory"]
data_df_new = spark.createDataFrame(data=data_new, schema = dep_cols)
display(data_df_new)
```

I need to do this in PySpark and I am new to it. Please help!

Comment: Are you using pyspark or pandas?

Comment: I need to do this in pyspark. I have found a solution to this on python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567933/pandas-drop-leading-zero-values-by-group, but need it in pyspark

Comment: Does that help. Happy to help further

Comment: @wwnde - it is working! thanks

Comment: @wwnde - could you please help with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71159189/add-rows-of-data-to-each-group-in-a-spark-dataframe

Comment: Signing of now. If not resolved I can look at it 12hra from now

Comment: @wwnde - thanks. it is still not resolved, i would highly appreciate your help. thanks

Comment: Will do it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Windowing function, to order by and incremenatlly sum or collect_list.

1. Filter where sum is greater than 0

or

2 filter list wehere has anything above 0. I prefered sum because it is faster.

```
w=Window.partitionBy('item','store').orderBy(F.asc('week')).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

df.withColumn("sums", F.sum('Sales').over(w)).filter(col('sums')>0).drop('sums').show()

+---+----+-----+----+-----+---+
| id|item|store|week|sales|inv|
+---+----+-----+----+-----+---+
|  2|   1|    5|   7|    1|  1|
|  3|   1|    5|   8|    1|  8|
|  4|   1|    5|   9|    1|  1|
|  5|   1|    5|  10|    1|  0|
|  8|   2|    3|   6|    3|  8|
|  9|   2|    3|   7|    0|  2|
| 10|   2|    3|   8|    0|  6|
| 11|   2|    3|   9|    6|  1|
+---+----+-----+----+-----+---+
```